# In wpgeodirectory, how to allow the listing author to toggle comments on/off

Tags: wordpress

Let us suppose that a store owner wants to hide all the comments and disable commenting for his store. How to achieve that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

a. Make a checkbox field with name 'geodir_togReview' : GD->Place settings->Checkbox->set HTML var name as 'togReview'

b. In geodirectory-compatibility.php add

```
// this line tells the tabs function to run our new function to remove a tab
add_filter('geodir_detail_page_tab_list_extend', 'geodir_detail_page_tab_list_remove_tab_conditional');

// this function removes the tab to the tabs list
function geodir_detail_page_tab_list_remove_tab_conditional($tab_array)
{
    // the $post var contains all the listing info so we can add conditions
    global $post, $preview;

    if ($preview)
        $is_place = $post->listing_type=='gd_place';
    else
        $is_place = $post->post_type=='gd_place';

    // HIDE OR SHOW
    if ($is_place && $post->geodir_togReview) {
        $tab_array['reviews']['is_active_tab'] = 0;
        $tab_array['reviews']['is_display'] = 0;
        //unset($tab_array['reviews']);//remove the tab
    } else {
        $tab_array['reviews']['is_active_tab'] = 1;
        $tab_array['reviews']['is_display'] = 1;
    }


    return $tab_array;
}
```